# Sublime Text 2 Package Control - error when trying to install new package

Tags: package, sublimetext2

I've upgraded to the most recent version of ST2 and when I try to install a package via package control I get the following error in the console:

```
 Exception in thread Thread-14:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File ".\threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
 File ".\Package Control.py", line 1890, in run
 File ".\Package Control.py", line 1759, in make_package_list
 File ".\Package Control.py", line 1182, in list_available_packages
 AttributeError: 'RepositoryDownloader' object has no attribute 'renamed_packages'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Exception is thrown it's usually a bug. In this case Package Control refers to a member variable it itself doesn't have.

Looks like an internal bug in Package Control. Please file an issue on Github:

https://github.com/wbond/sublime_package_control